# mysql google maps query store within user location custom drawing tool?

Tags: mysql, google-maps, maps

i am using this tool [Drawing Tool places](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/68b8f6a586c512cfc768#file-gmaps-drawing-tools-places-htm) to draw places inside the map , i am trying to get the place which covers user location.

for example :

**user is not inside pink or orange shapes. ( places )** 
[image]

**user inside 2nd shape ( orange place )** 
[image]

each shape has array of long/lat , i've added them to the places table, for example the orange shape array is :

```
cursel: polygon [object Object]; pos: undefined ; path: [ 53.750107,-1.459851 , 53.750842,-1.461568 , 53.749954,-1.461825 , 53.749751,-1.464272 , 53.749117,-1.466203 , 53.748812,-1.469336 , 53.742493,-1.466074 , 53.738686,-1.46337 , 53.739143,-1.4538 , 53.740539,-1.45247 , 53.746985,-1.452899 , 53.749345,-1.455903 , 53.749218,-1.458092 ,
```

user location is : 53.746858,-1.46513

** places table records :**

```
placeId | long  | lat 
1 | 53.750919 | -1.471567
1 | 53.749675 | -1.473541
1 | 53.749066 | -1.472383
........
2 | 53.750107 | -1.459851
2 | 53.750842 | -1.461568
2 | 53.749954 | -1.461825
2 | 53.749751 | -1.464272
.......
```

i am doing this query :

```
select * from places where lat > '$lat' AND long < '$long'
```

here is the Tables structure :

```
//Place Name and ID
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `place` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name ` varchar(70) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

//Place Long/Lat borders <<-- here where i store the Array of long/lat of the place after it being draw  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `places` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lat ` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `long ` varchar(70) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

> My problem with mysql query how to get the correct place
>   within its range if its cover user location

any idea is very much appreciated

Comment: related question: [sql query for points in polygon/rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838230/sql-query-for-points-in-polygon-rectangle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rick James said using the [Spatial Data Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-types.html).

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `place` (
  `id`         int(10) unsigned   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`       varchar(70)        NOT NULL,
  `geometry`   polygon            NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  SPATIAL INDEX `si_place_geometry` (`geometry`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

add place records:

```
INSERT INTO `place`(
       `name`,
       `geometry`)
VALUES (
       'area01',
        POLYGON(
          LINESTRING(
            POINT(53.750107, -1.459851), POINT(53.750842, -1.461568),
            POINT(53.749954, -1.461825), POINT(53.749751, -1.464272),
            POINT(53.749117, -1.466203), POINT(53.748812, -1.469336),
            POINT(53.742493, -1.466074), POINT(53.738686, -1.46337 ),
            POINT(53.739143, -1.4538  ), POINT(53.740539, -1.45247 ),
            POINT(53.746985, -1.452899), POINT(53.749345, -1.455903),
            POINT(53.749218, -1.458092), POINT(53.750107, -1.459851))
        )
       );
```

query statement might like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `place`
 WHERE ST_Within(POINT(53.746858, -1.46513), `geometry`);

*************************** 1. row ***************************
      id: 1
    name: area01
geometry: ...binary data...
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: creating the Table , inserting and query , the perfect answer + Thank u

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from places where lat > '$lat' AND long < '$long'
```

only checks for being northwest of [$lat, $long].  So, it, or any variant of it, is probably useless for the question.

Make a `SPATIAL` index on `the_polygon`.

Use `WHERE  ST_Within(user_point, the_polygon)` do see if the user is in the polygon.

If you need more help, lease provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can discuss it in context.

Comment: i have 2 tables , 1 for place name and increment id , and the 2nd for place border and place id of table 1 , i will update the question

Comment: i have update the question with ur requirements , what is the `the_polygon` ? its first time for me with mysql GEO

Comment: @Jack - You said you had a `POLYGON`; I made up the column name (`the_polygon`).

Comment: @Jack - It is rarely useful to have two tables in a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: thanks for the advice i think this is what i need to use `polygon` , can u update ur answer what i have to change in my db structure and how to query it ? i think i am in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got a `places` table which contains all locations of each `place`, you can simply retrieve user location from `places` table to figure out the correct place.

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM place 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM places WHERE lat = '$lat' AND long = '$long');
```

If this user doesn't locate in a certain place within your `places` table, you will get am empty result set.

In addition, for a better performance I would suggest you replacing `varchar(70)` to `float` or `double`, and create an index for each locations, e.g. `UNIQUE KEY location (lat, long)`.

Comment: `=` will not work . each place has multiple long/lat

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But each long-lat pair must be associated with a unique place id. And you want to get the place id by a specific long-lat pair. Right?

Comment: please try the drawing tool i've provided in my question see how its draw the area , i want mysql query which will get the place by user long/loat if user inside this area

Comment: OK, I'll try it later today.